# OpenVPN speed tweaks for VPS(Windows)

Tags: windows, networking, openvpn

**Background**:

I have an OpenVPN server running on my Windows 10 VPS. The Internet connection of VPS is ~**750 Mbps** for Download and ~**450** Mbps for upload (Obtained by multiple speedtest.net tests). The VPS has 2 vCPU and 8 GB RAM. The VPS serves only two clients of OpenVPN. However, the speedtest for clients normally shows **30 Mbp**s of the test while VPN is enabled.

**What I have tried**:

- Please see the config

**Config**:

- *Server*

```
;local a.b.c.d

--duplicate-cn

port 443

;proto tcp

proto udp

sndbuf 393216

rcvbuf 393216

push "sndbuf 393216"

push "rcvbuf 393216"

txqueuelen 4000

tun-mtu 9000 

mssfix 0

fragment 0

;dev tap

dev tun

ca "ca.crt"

cert "ERVER.crt"

key "C:\\SE.key"  # This file should be kept secret

dh "dh.pem"

;topology subnet

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

;server-bridge 10.8.0.4 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.50 10.8.0.100

;server-bridge

;push "route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0"

;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"

push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"

push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"

keepalive 10 120

tls-auth "tls-auth.key" 0 # This file is secret

cipher AES-128-CBC

persist-key

persist-tun

;mute 20

explicit-exit-notify 1
```

- *Client*

```
dev tun
proto udp
remote IP 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
key-direction 1
cipher AES-128-CBC
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<tls-auth>
</tls-auth>
```

Comment: How fast is the internet connection of your VPN clients? OpenVPN is not known for incredible performance, but 80Mbps should be perfectly possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
client
dev tun
remote-cert-tls server

compress
proto udp 
cipher aes-128-cbc
ncp-disable
fast-io

sndbuf 512000
rcvbuf 512000
txqueuelen 2000

pull
nobind
reneg-sec 0
resolv-retry infinite
verb 3
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-random
mute-replay-warnings
route-delay 10
```

- Use UDP for better OpenVPN performance.
- Disable compression
- Disable cipher negotiation